# How to get column attributes from a query using PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I need to get the fields attributes from a query, like in this question:[How to get column attributes query from table name using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928118/how-to-get-column-attributes-query-from-table-name-using-postgresql)
but for a query, is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Which programming language are you using? PL/pgSQL? Java? C++?

Comment: @Starglider ... and the `psycopg2` database driver?

Comment: Yes psycopg2 database driver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're using `psycopg2` as your database driver, then the `cursor.description` field is what you want:

```
import pprint
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('');
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("SELECT 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 'text' as colblah");
pprint.pprint(curs.description)
```

produces:

```
(Column(name='col1', type_code=23, display_size=None, internal_size=4, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None),
 Column(name='col2', type_code=23, display_size=None, internal_size=4, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None),
 Column(name='colblah', type_code=705, display_size=None, internal_size=-2, precision=None, scale=None, null_ok=None))
```

The type codes are PostgreSQL's internal object IDs.

For more detail [see the `psycopg2` manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html), which explains how to turn the type oids into type names, among other things.