# How to get the list of column names for all indexes on a table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, database-indexes, database-metadata

I have this query to get the list of indexes on a table:

```
SELECT
    ns.nspname as schema_name,
    tab.relname as table_name,
    cls.relname as index_name,
    am.amname as index_type,
    idx.indisprimary as is_primary,
    idx.indisunique as is_unique
FROM
    pg_index idx
INNER JOIN pg_class cls ON cls.oid=idx.indexrelid
INNER JOIN pg_class tab ON tab.oid=idx.indrelid
INNER JOIN pg_am am ON am.oid=cls.relam
INNER JOIN pg_namespace ns on ns.oid=tab.relnamespace
WHERE ns.nspname = @Schema AND tab.relname = @Name
```

It seems to be working right. But now I need a query for the list of columns and I'm having trouble understanding how the system views work.

Specifically what I'm looking for are:

- [index name or id for matching to the first query]
- Order in index
- Column name
- ascending or descending
- sorted column or included column

Ideally I would like to get the above items for all indexes of a given table at one time.

---

Note that I'm looking for more than just the column names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List columns with indexes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204058/list-columns-with-indexes-in-postgresql)

Comment: @Andreas That's not an exact match because I'm asking for more information than just the column names.

Answer (score 7):

Use the system catalog information function [**`pg_get_indexdef(index_oid)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to get complete information (including the list of index expressions) - in a query against [`pg_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-index.html) to get all indexes for a given table:

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid) || ';' AS idx
FROM   pg_index
WHERE  indrelid = 'public.tbl'::regclass;  -- optionally schema-qualified
```

Related:

- [Django/PostgreSQL varchar to UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35139818/django-postgresql-varchar-to-uuid/35142957#35142957)
- [Copy indexes from one table to another](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120194/3684)

If you rely on an unqualified table name (without schema) you depend on the current `search_path` setting and might get results for a table of the same name in a different schema.

***Alternatively***, you can join to `pg_attribute` by hand to get individual columns like demonstrated in these related answers:

- [How to get column attributes query from table name using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928118/how-to-get-column-attributes-query-from-table-name-using-postgresql/15931552#15931552)
- [Find tables with multiple indexes on same column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204733/3684)

Key ingredient is to join like this:

```
FROM   pg_index idx
LEFT   JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = idx.indrelid
                          AND a.attnum = ANY(idx.indkey)
                          AND a.attnum > 0
```

The manual about `pg_index.indkey`:

> This is an array of `indnatts` values that indicate which table columns
>   this index indexes. For example a value of `1 3` would mean that the
>   first and the third table columns make up the index entries. Key
>   columns come before non-key (included) columns. A zero in this array
>   indicates that the corresponding index attribute is an expression over
>   the table columns, rather than a simple column reference.

Adding `AND a.attnum > 0` is not technically necessary as there is no `a.attnum = 0`. But it makes the query clearer and it won't hurt. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-attribute.html)

> Ordinary columns are numbered from 1 up. System columns, such as oid, have (arbitrary) negative numbers.

Be aware, that there the *"list of column names"* can actually contain expressions, too. And since Postgres 11 there are also "included" columns (no expressions there). `pg_get_indexdef()` deals with all possible complications out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Other databases I've seen require calculated columns at the table level first, you can't put the calculations directly into the index.

Comment: @JonathanAllen: Oracle, DB2 and to a certain Firebird as well also support also creating an index on an expression. This is not unique to Postgres

Comment: @JonathanAllen: OTOH, Postgres does not support true generated columns - yet. There is ongoing work to add the feature in Postgres 12. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/939860

Answer (score 4):

You can puzzle it together from the system catalogs, as Erwin Brandstetter detailed.

Here is a query that will return the information you want:

```
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass AS indexname,                                    
       k.i AS index_order,                                                     
       i.indnkeyatts,                                                          
       coalesce(a.attname,                                                     
                (('{' || pg_get_expr(                                          
                            i.indexprs,                                        
                            i.indrelid                                         
                         )                                                     
                      || '}')::text[]                                          
                )[k.i]                                                         
               ) AS index_column,                                              
       i.indoption[k.i - 1] = 0 AS ascending,                                  
       k.i <= i.indnkeyatts AS is_key                                          
FROM pg_index i                                                                
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(i.indkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS k(attnum, i)         
   LEFT JOIN pg_attribute AS a                                                 
      ON i.indrelid = a.attrelid AND k.attnum = a.attnum                       
WHERE i.indrelid = 'schemaname.tablename'::regclass;
```

This query will only work from PostgreSQL v11 on (but there are no covering Indexes before v11).

Also, the query will fail if the indexed expression contains a comma; I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Joining to an unnested set is more accurate than my short `a.attnum = ANY(idx.indkey)` - in case of (questionable!) duplicated columns in the list of index expressions). But you have a couple regressions, too. 1. `indnkeyatts`: needs to be `indnatts` before pg 11, *included* columns missing in pg 11. 2. schema-qualify `'tablename'::regclass` to be sure. 3. `pg_get_expr()` returns a list of index expressions which may contain commas that invalidate your concatenated array literal. Consider the example: `to_tsvector('simple', col)`. Fixing that gets messy. `pg_get_indexdef()` avoids the trouble.

Comment: The question is specifically about PostgreSQL v11, I guess, because it asks about "included columns". But you are right about the comma in the expression. I'll see if I can do anything about that.

Answer (score 1):

Version 10.4

```
SELECT idx.indexrelid::regclass AS indexname,                                    
       k.i AS index_order,                                                     
       --i.indnkeyatts,                                                          
       coalesce(att.attname,                                                     
                (('{' || pg_get_expr(                                          
                            idx.indexprs,                                        
                            idx.indrelid                                         
                         )                                                     
                      || '}')::text[]                                          
                )[k.i]                                                         
               ) AS index_column,                                              
       pg_index_column_has_property(idx.indexrelid,k.i::int,'asc') AS ascending,                                  
       k.i != -1 AS is_key                                          
FROM pg_index idx                                                                
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(idx.indkey) WITH ORDINALITY AS k(attnum, i)         
   LEFT JOIN pg_attribute AS att                                                 
      ON idx.indrelid = att.attrelid AND k.attnum = att.attnum
```